# query result only returns one value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to see multiple values from my query but when I start this query, the result has only one value

```
function get_prove_associati($num) {
    $this->db->select("prove.*");
    $this->db->where("prove.numero",$num);
    return $this->db->get("prove")->row_array();
}
```

In my db , there are four rows, not only one

Comment: Please do not edit the answers of other users (as you did with B.K's post) but instead update your question with the details and add a comment below the other one's post regarding the update.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), `row_array()` returns only the first row. Instead, `result_array()` is the correct method to return all found results.

Comment: If i use row_array(0 or 1 or 2 ) there is result. But if i use result_array , the result is null...

Answer (score 0):

You got four types of returns:

1. `row_array` one value as an array
2. `row` one value as an object
3. `result_array` all values as an array
4. `result` all values as an object

Answer (score 0):

To see all results you have to change `row_array()` to `result_array()`

```
function get_prove_associati($num) {
    $this->db->select("prove.*");
    $this->db->where("prove.numero",$num);
    return $this->db->get("prove")->result_array();//updated here
}
```

Comment: If i use result_array() the result is null .
I need N result for checkbox

Comment: @PhantomMoore: print executed query  by using $this->db->last_query()....and check data is available or not by running raw query in database.

Comment: SELECT `prove`.* FROM `prove` WHERE `prove`.`prove.numero` = '32'

I have N checkbox, i confront   id service   == prova[id]   , if it   checked="checked"

Comment: @PhantomMoore: checking once by printing result by using print_r(); you will get result

Comment: Nothing , i use print_r( $x["voto"]) .

Comment: @PhantomMoore No...just print total object....i mean once your quering done